# How to put a td element next to a h1 element?

Tags: html

Probably a basic question but how would I go about putting a table next to a header? [Image of What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnuPx.png)

The following is a small part of the code but it should cover the header and one of the images that I want to move next to the h1 element.

```
        #header 
        {
            background-color:#E3BA00;
            color:black;
            width:918px;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;
        }

        </style>

    </head>

    <!-- Now the body of the page is defined. -->

    <body>

        <div id="header">
        <h1>English To Swedish Translator</h1>
        <h2>By fgfgfg <h2>
        </div>


        <!-- A table is now created where key elements can be organized. -->

        <table border="0" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#006A8B">

          <!-- Start a new row... -->
          <tr>

         <td>
            <img src    = "http:thelink"
            width       = "150"
            height      = "90"
            border      = "0">
          </td>
```

Comment: Do you intend to put the table tag into the div having the id of header?

Comment: Yes, I want the table to be part of the header essentially, but I want the two pictures, one to the right, and one to the left of the title (the h1 element).

Comment: I see. How is it looking alike if you simply put the table into the div as it is?

Comment: The table just goes on top of the title.

Comment: I figured it out, I just had to use the html element align to align it to the right and left.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to use the html element align to align it to the right and left.

Comment: There is no such thing as a HTML element called `align`. If you meant the `align` attribute, that has been obsolete for several years and shouldn't be used.